# cannot implement in AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepickerdialog

This is my code and what I've tried so far :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity  ()   {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}
```

And it seems I cannot change to

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implement DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetLisTener   {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}
```

i cant change mycode to import,extends  that error

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: First code block is written in Kotlin, the second is written in mix of Kotlin, Java and nothing. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used Kotlin

For Kotlin make like this:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.DatePicker

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think you are familiar with an interface in java, or how a class should implement one, the syntax is therefore quite incorrect.

The correct form should be :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener   {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}
```

If this is indeed what you want to achieve, please see here [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

Comment: It is not a Kotlin syntax. Yet still, your class is in Kotlin. And you are providing link to Java one.

Answer (score 0):

You are, probably, using Kotlin language instead of Java. File with Kotlin ends with .kt extention. You can replace it with Java file (extention .java) containing this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implement DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```